# QComboBox.setPlaceholderText() not working

Tags: python, user-interface, qtpy

I am currently trying to make some changes to a GUI application, which uses `qtpy` extensively. For a certain condition, the text for a combo box is to be set to a certain value.

For this I used `self.colormapComboBox.setPlaceholderText("RGB")`, where colormapComboBox is an object of the class `qtpy.QtWidgets.QComboBox`. Documentation referred: [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QComboBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QComboBox.setPlaceholderText)

It results in the error:

`AttributeError: 'QComboBox' object has no attribute 'setPlaceholderText'`

What can be done to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make your comboBox editable. Then you need to use this line of code. `self.colormapComboBox.lineEdit().setPlaceholderText("RGB")`

Comment: I did as you said. It results in this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setPlaceholderText'`

Comment: I didn't set combobox b capital. I have edited it. Copy it and try it again